# Android setText is not working

Tags: android, text, android-edittext, settext

SetText is not working for an editText. i change the edittext id, name etc. but its not working. can anyone help me?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

    buttonContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    textPhoneN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

    /////////// for set message into compose window
    textPhoneN.setText("sdf");
  }
```

textPhoneN is not set any text in oncreate().

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#6666E0"
android:gravity="end"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:hint="To"
        android:inputType="text|phone" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#00004C"
        android:text="Add Contact"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextSMS"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Message"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00004C"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I follow your suggestion but still no result

Comment: looks sane - please show your layout

Comment: Is this an Activity or Fragment?

Comment: Show us the layout please

Comment: If you changed ID, you may want to rebuild the whole app to ensure everything is compiled properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove  `android:inputType="text|phone"` and try.

Comment: add more details to your answer or try to give some explanation to it.

Comment: its good that answer worked but adding explanation help other user to understand why that worked and also helps the answer get more votes. Hope you are geeting my pont.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set a `android:inputType` for the `EditText` in your XML? For example, if you set `android:inputType="number"` for your `textPhoneN` then you will not be able to set `"sdf"` because it isn't numeric data (it will not throw any error, but the text will not be set)

Instead, try
`textPhoneN.setText("12345");`

If this doesn't work either, maybe your `EditText` is disabled in XML.

Comment: So Firoze? I have a question.